# Standalone play application with embedded java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two web applications. One is Java based big enterprise application which requires java 8. Second is a tiny Scala+Play-based standalone http server which requires java version <= 1.7.0_21

I have jdk 1.7.0_21 with some additional libraries located in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`. Is there some way to build second application with embedded jdk and additional jdk libraries? The goal is to install only java 8 on production server and deploy second application without installation java 7 itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you though of using `docker` and have the Play application run inside a container?

https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker supplies allready a lot of functionality out of the box for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to **not** use Java 8 to run your Play application? As far as I know, Java is [backward compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility), meaning that you can build your app with Java 7 and run it with Java 8.

So, give it a try and see if everything works as expected. If so, I won't need to manage the complexity of bundling JDK 7 with your Play application.

Comment: Yes. I use some third-party library which is not working on java 8, which was tested so many times. Believe me man, I'd be happy to use java 8 everywhere.

Comment: I believe you. :-) But I wonder what this 3rd party lib was doing to break backward compatibility. Can you reveal the guilt library?

Comment: Its russian cryptographic library called cryptopro jcp. They have two versions: for newest java and jdk 1.7.0_21, but my company purchased only second one. So, we have to use it as is.